# Why UICollectionView scroll to top in ipad if you are at the end of the list and click a popover?

Tags: ipad, scroll, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` and when it goes long and I am at bottom of the list, I clcik on a cell in the list and a pop over shows up. It makes the UICollectionView scroll to top.

How can I stop it. this doesn't work:

```
collectionView.scrollsToTop = NO;
```

This looks bad and I am not sure what should be CGPointMake(?, ?):

```
[CollectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(?, ?) animated:YES];
```

Comment: You may need to post some code here. What does the popover do?

Comment: It is a popover that opens a view controller like this: [self.detailsPopover presentPopoverFromRect:cell.frame inView:self. collectionView
                                      permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

Comment: You able to find any solution???

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by setting:

```
    [self.collectionView setPagingEnabled:NO];
```